# What does the "donut" tag stand for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I once, not long ago saw the tag [donut](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut), floating on the right on my screen in the tags. What is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

It is not supposed to be there. It was probably a joke.